# Creating a Domain Shared Contact does not display the contact's full name in the Directory

Tags: google-api

We are currently using the Google Apps for Education service. Using the Domain Shared Contacts API from https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/?hl=fr,
and posting the sample shared contact of "Elizabeth Bennet" to our tenant,
the shared contact shows up in the Directory as "liz@gmail.com" instead of
"Elizabeth Bennet"

This appears to be true despite populating the contact entry gd:name elements

```
<gd:name>
     <gd:givenName>Elizabeth</gd:givenName>
     <gd:familyName>Bennet</gd:familyName>
     <gd:fullName>Elizabeth Bennet</gd:fullName>
</gd:name>
```

Is there another XML attribute or element I should be using such that the
Directory always display the full name of the contact, rather than the
primary email address of the contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you need to specify the GData-Version in the header of the request.

GData-Version: 3.0